# Can the quality of text in an image be improved?

Tags: windows, images, image-editing

I've a lot of .PNG images that contain text. Is there a software/algorithm to improve the text's quality?

For example:

[image]

As you can see in the pic, OCR is not an option, since this isnt English and the platform I'm going to use these images on doesn't perfectly support this language.

Comment: Is this text only, or text with an image? EG, words over a picture.

Comment: Post updated with an example (I can also remove the surrounding and keep the text only)

Answer (score 5):

Software like [Tesseract (open source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29) and [Adobe Acrobat (proprietary)](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html) contain OCR tools that are preconfigured to extract text from a picture. You could look into using these. If you want to figure out and design algorithms to increase the text's readability, then you could go through some literature on image processing and write code to perform the transform functions on the given image.

Answer (score 3):

### OCR

You can use [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) software to convert images of text into true text - this will allow you to render the text at any level of quality you desire. OCR software is often included with image scanners and graphics suites.

[Arabic OCR software](http://www.google.com/search?q=arabic+ocr) is available. Even if the target platform doesn't support Arabic, you can OCR on a platform that does and then rasterise the text to a higher quality image for deployment.

### Use "SHARPEN"

If you want to apply transformations such as sharpening or edge detection you can use tools such as [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#vision)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using something like Photoshop - it is designed for things like this. And, it allows you to batch process so it is ideal if you have multiple files.

Even Photoshop elements allows you to batch but it's limited compared to the full version (but easier on the wallet). Here is an example of [batching with Elements](http://www.photokaboom.com/photography/learn/photoshop_elements/batch_processing/1_batch_processing.htm).

You can get a [free trial of Photoshop Elements](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop_elements&loc=en_us).