# Batch image replace 2 colors

Tags: linux, windows, images, png

I know there is already such question but it didn't helped me. I have a lot of image files, where I want to change purple RGB(255, 0, 255) to transparent (it is png). Is there any app which could do it quickly? I use Linux, but I am able to use Windows tool.

Comment: Which question are you referring to and why didn't it help you?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/460937/batch-image-program-to-replace-2-colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most questions which involve batch transformations of raster image files, the answer is to be found in the [netpbm toolkit](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/). In this case, if your png images don't already have an alpha channel, the simplest solution will be to convert from png to pnm and back again; on the way back, you can specify a transparent colour:

```
pngtopnm $file | pnmtopng -transparent==rgb:ff/00/ff > new.$file
```

If your png images do already have an alpha channel (or a different transparent background colour), you'll need to extract the existing alpha channel and then combine it with a new alpha channel consisting of the "purple" pixels. See the `-alpha` command line option for `pngtopnm` and `pnmtopng`. You can use `ppmchange` to create bitmaps corresponding to a particular colour in an image. You can use `ppmcomp` or `pnmarith` to compose two images. (If the images are bitmaps, `pnmarith -max` and `pnmarith -min` are bitwise `or` and `and`, respectively.)

If the transformation is not available in the netpbm toolkit, it's usually pretty easy to do it with a shell script or a python program; just convert the images to plain format, which is pretty easy to work with.